# Is it possible to serialize a java class object to a class file?

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to reverse engineer a java class that is loaded by custom class loader.

I tried to store the binary content, and later tried to decompile, but decompiler complained it as not a typical java class, I understood that class is loaded dynamically.

Now at runtime I have class object. Is it possible to serialize to a class file which follows the same convention as sun java class.

Added : alternatively, is there any decompiler API available which can work on java class object?

Comment: there is no decompiler API but you can get the bytecodes. if you have the class object, you just have the processed by the JVM bytecode, the bytecode itself is 'generally' unavailble.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but if you have the "binary content" of the class, my low-level [Solum](https://github.com/TkTech/Solum) library would likely be able to help you where a higher-level decompiler would fail. You can use `solum.bytecode.Disassembler` directly to decompile bytecode without having a valid class.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (imo) to get around the case is directly hacking `java.lang.ClassLoader` and replacing it to track any loaded class look for `protected final Class<?> defineClass(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain)` and replace it w/ your own version and a hook. When you compile your own version of java.lang.ClassLoader, just use `java - -Xbootclasspath/p`

Alternatively installing some instrumentation can yield similar effects.

Happy hacking!

Comment: So even if the class is instrumented at runtime before it is emitted from the ClassLoader, we'll see the results here? That could useful.

Comment: pretty much yes. That's where the actual bytecode goes into "JVM stuff".

Answer (score 0):

Ehhhh. Why does the decompiler complain, exactly? Some code simply cannot be decompiled. For example, if the byte code pushes, but then doesn't pop, there's just no Java equivalent for that.

Try and inspect the byte code. A quick peek with javap might be quite revealing already.

Comment: 1. Assume for some reason you give me a class file which was manually edited using binary editor, but provide me a class loader to load. Now all the decompiler for typical class would fail. 2. If I could construct original class file, I don't need to worry about byte code.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'm getting it. But forget about the object instance, then. What you want is reflection on the class. You want to reflect about a class's byte code representation, bypassing the class loader.